# How to format a new line for each condition, only if more than two conditions (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, formatter

How can I configure Eclipse formatter to format chained conditions automatically (ctrl + shift + f) like

```
// if only two conditions -> same line
if (true && true) {
  doSomething();   
}

// if more than two conditions -> new line for each condition
if (true
    && true
    && true
    && true) {
  doSomething();   
}
```

I could not find a proper option in Line Wrapping-settings.